# Adding a `cec-gpio` dtoverlay for CEC debugging

Tags: gpio, hardware, hdmi, device-tree

I want to build a CEC Debugger as described in the [Kernel.org documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/media/cec.html#making-a-cec-debugger) with my Pi Zero 2 W, I plan on using something like this:

[image: HDMI Pass Through Breakout Board]

I am having trouble with the final instructions listed to enable the `cec-gpio` device tree overlay. The instructions are as follows:

> This kernel patch will hook up the cec-gpio driver correctly to e.g. arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dts:

```
cec-gpio@7 {
        compatible = "cec-gpio";
        cec-gpios = <&gpio 7 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH|GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
        hpd-gpios = <&gpio 17 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        v5-gpios = <&gpio 22 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
};

cec-gpio@8 {
        compatible = "cec-gpio";
        cec-gpios = <&gpio 8 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH|GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
        hpd-gpios = <&gpio 27 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        v5-gpios = <&gpio 24 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
};
```

> This dts change will enable two cec GPIO devices: I typically use one to send/receive CEC commands and the other to monitor. If you monitor using an unconfigured CEC adapter then it will use GPIO interrupts which makes monitoring very accurate.

I am unfamiliar with dts files but I have managed to create one, built it and copied it to /boot/overlays:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>

/ {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";

        fragment@0 {
                target-path = "/";
                __overlay__ {
                        cec-gpio@7 {
                                compatible = "cec-gpio";
                                cec-gpios = <&gpio 7 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH|GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
                                hpd-gpios = <&gpio 17 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
                                v5-gpios = <&gpio 22 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

I have updated my `/boot/config.txt` to include this overlay last and there appear to be no errors. I can see something when I run:

```
> sudo ls -R /sys | grep cec
cec
/sys/bus/cec:
/sys/bus/cec/devices:
cec0
/sys/bus/cec/drivers:
cec-gpio@7
platform:20200000.gpio--platform:cec-gpio@7
cec-gpio@7
/sys/devices/platform/cec-gpio@7:
/sys/devices/platform/cec-gpio@7/power:
consumer:platform:cec-gpio@7
cec0
/sys/devices/platform/soc/20902000.hdmi/cec0:
/sys/devices/platform/soc/20902000.hdmi/cec0/power:
platform:20200000.gpio--platform:cec-gpio@7
/sys/devices/virtual/devlink/platform:20200000.gpio--platform:cec-gpio@7:
cec-gpio@7
/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/cec-gpio@7:
cec-gpios
cec
/sys/kernel/debug/cec:
cec0
/sys/kernel/debug/cec/cec0:
cec
/sys/module/cec:
/sys/module/cec/holders:
/sys/module/cec/notes:
/sys/module/cec/parameters:
/sys/module/cec/sections:
```

But from this output and from running `ls /dev/cec*` I can only see 1 CEC device: the inital HDMI port.

What steps can I take to debug this?

Comment: Ordinarily, `dts` files are **source** files that must be compiled before they can be loaded as an *overlay* and used. What is it that makes you think you can use a `dts` file directly to accomplish this? A few words about what you're trying to do might help us help you.

Comment: The reference you've cited from the kernel docs lacks many details - this may be intentional. [This document](https://archive.fosdem.org/2019/schedule/event/hdmi_cec/attachments/slides/3420/export/events/attachments/hdmi_cec/slides/3420/fosdem_2019_cec_status.pdf) at least gives you a PoC.

Comment: Hey @Seamus I understand that a `dts` file must be compiled, I used the command `sudo dtc -O dtb -b 0 -o /boot/overlays/cec-spy.dtbo ./cec-spy.dts` after installing `apt-get install linux-headers` and linking them to the include folder. 
From the presentation you linked, and the waybackmachine, I found a patch file that I might be able to use

Answer (score 2):

After much debugging and trying to figure this out, I have finally managed to "install" my device. The `dts` in my question is for all intents and purposes correct! However the default build of the Linux Kernel does not include the supported driver. The steps I used to enable `/dev/cec1` are based on the Kernel guide: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html and this allowed me to *cross compile* the kernel needed.

On a linux machine that is not the Rasp

1. Setup a dev environment

```
sudo apt install git bc bison flex libssl-dev make libc6-dev libncurses5-dev
```

2. download the kernel git repo

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
```

3. apply the default build config

```
cd linux
KERNEL=kernel
make bcmrpi_defconfig
```

3. Configure your version of the kernel

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- menuconfig
```

and then hunt through the configuration program to set the following options

- General Setup > Preemption Model > Choose option "Preemptible Kernel (Low-Latency Desktop)"
- Exit to top menu
- Device Drivers > HDMI CEC drivers > Select "Generic GPIO-based CEC driver" and press Y
- Save and Exit

5. Build

```
make -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage modules dtbs
```

6. make a staging area for all this

```
mkdir -p ~/staging/boot/custom-kernel/overlays/
mkdir -p ~/staging/lib
```

6. Copy/Build drivers to a staging

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=~/staging/lib modules_install
```

7. Copy device tree and images to a folder

```
sudo cp ~/linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage ~/staging/boot/custom-kernel/$KERNEL.img
sudo cp ~/linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/*.dtb ~/staging/boot/custom-kernel/
sudo cp ~/linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* ~/staging/boot/custom-kernel/overlays/
sudo cp ~/linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README ~/staging/boot/custom-kernel/overlays/
```

8. Copy the two folders in your staging directory to the root of the Raspberry Pi file system. In my case I had `/boot` mounted as `fat32` and I has to mount the other partition `/` which is `ext4` format

```
PC              SD Card
~/staging
   lib/    ->   /lib/
   boot/   ->   /boot/
```

9. Update the `config.txt` to use your new Kernel by adding this line somewhere:

```
os_prefix=custom-kernel/
```

10. Then I was able to copy my `cec-spy.dtbo` overlay and test it out using `sudo dtoverlay cec-spy` and sure enough a new `/dev/cec1` device appeared!

Answer (score 0):

in above procedure you did build seperately for cec-spy.dtbo?.

following newely created for cec-spy.dts?.

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>

/ {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";

        fragment@0 {
                target-path = "/";
                __overlay__ {
                        cec-gpio@7 {
                                compatible = "cec-gpio";
                                cec-gpios = <&gpio 7 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH|GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
                                hpd-gpios = <&gpio 17 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
                                v5-gpios = <&gpio 22 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

I tried to build using this command **sudo dtc -O dtb -b 0 -o /boot/overlays/cec-spy.dtbo ./cec-spy.dts**  but i am facing the error.Can you confirm any steps is missed?.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/131788)